# Create Snapchat-like playback after recording video

Tags: avfoundation, swift2

The snapchat camera can take a short clip and then play it back instantly to the user. Then the user has the option to use this video. I am trying to replicate this feature.

The path I was going down was using 
`AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate` and calling
`captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!, fromConnection connection: AVCaptureConnection!)` 
to store  a list of `UIImage`.

Then I used `AVAssetWriter` to create a .mp4 file and saved it to documents. Then once it saved I would just play the video using `AVPlayer`.

This worked however `AVPlayer` is not the layout I want. **I simply want to show the the images in order at the same frame rate I recorded them in**

What is the best way to do this?